# Vertical center a rotated div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I don't get it ;-(

I want to center a div with a text contained in another div. The inner div is rotated by 90 degres. So far so good. My problem is that I can't get the inner div to align horizontal to the left of the outer div.
How can this be done?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4vrf7pg/7/)

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        12345678901234567890
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 300px; 
    width: 30px;   
}

.inner {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Painted]

Comment: you could use transform-origin to choose where rotation is done and update other values: http://jsfiddle.net/r4vrf7pg/4/

Comment: Oh sorry, it is only the first half of the story. I forgot to mention, that the outer div should only be about 30px. (I added the styles from isherwood)

Comment: And the border of the innver div should include the whole text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the inner div to `position:absolute` too.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4vrf7pg/8/

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 30px;
}
.inner {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        12345678901234567890
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.inner {
    ...
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r4vrf7pg/3/)**

There are probably easier ways to accomplish this. Rotating the parent element would eliminate some complexity, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** So this won't work if you plan on making more of these with different widths but for right now if I just add `margin-left: -72px;` to the `.inner` class it aligns to the left of the inside of the `.outer` div.

```
.inner {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -72px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Might need to add some width to .outer though, I don't believe it is as wide as it was originally.